# CSS property visibility hidden is being ignored

Tags: css

I have the following html structure:

```css
.screens > .screen {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.screen.pt-page-current {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="screens">
  <div class="info-screen screen screen-viewer"> <!-- does not have pt-page-current so this has visibility: hidden -->
    <div class="screens">
      <div class="loading-screen screen pt-page-current"> <!-- receives visibility: hidden for the first rule, but the rule is overwritten in the second rule, because of the pt-page-current class to visibility: visible -->
        The page is currently loading.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-screen screen screen-viewer">
    <div class="screens">
      <div class="menu-screen screen pt-page-current">
        You accessed the menu.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The idea here would be to create a type of single page app (a screen viewer), that can have multiple screens (`.screen` class), but at most one screen visible at the time (the screen marked with the `.pt-current-page`).

Each "screen" object in turn, can be another **screen viewer**, containing sub screens, and etc. For transitionining between screens I am trying to work with the `visibility` property in css. My problem is, that based on just the above code, I would expect my browser to display nothing, as both outer `.screen` classes have the `visibility: hidden` property set, yet the browser displays the inner `.screen` from both outer `.screen` classes.

See fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/y57cs4u8/).

Am I misinterpreting how visibility should work, or is this some kind of a bug?

Comment: Parent element visibility will not impact child element visibility. You can try Display:none but obviously it has different behavior than visibility

Comment: @Zain this is not my understanding - if a parent is hidden it’s children will not show either, whatever their own visibility setting.

Comment: You are up against specificity. Both the child screen elements also have pt-page-current class.

Comment: Do you want to use visibility: hidden? It will still save the space for the page even though it doesn't show its content? Would you be better off with display: none which won't render the content at all?

Comment: @AHaworth no, the outer `.screen` elements do not have that class, and I was expecting that an outer elements visibility, would control the inner elements visibility also - but unfortunately, @Zain is right in this regard, the inner-most elements visibility setting trumps all previously set visibility settings unfortunately. Because these screens will be animated, I was opting for visibility usage, but in the end, I managed to resolve this with `display` property.

Comment: I've added two comments to the code snippet above to demonstrate. My expected behaviour would have been, that the outer `.screen` elements `visibility: hidden` rule, should hide the element from view, even if any inner elements have an explicit `visibility: visible` set, yet this is not the case, as @Zain pointed out.

Comment: It was beause of the specificity, an outer element that has visibility hidden means the inneer elements will not be seen. Your outer elements did not have visibility hidden.

Comment: @AHaworth incorrect. please check either in the fiddle or in the snippet with an inspector. The outer element indeed has `visibility: hidden`, and the inner element has `visibility: visible`, yet the inner elements are still visible. If you change the `visibility` property to `display` with `block` and `none`, the inner element will respect the `none` display of it's outer element, and will not show. This is not the case with visibility, the inner element does not respect the visibility of the outer element. Apparently, this is by design: https://jakearchibald.com/2014/visible-undoes-hidden/

Comment: Yes, you are right, apologies. Descendants will be visible if they set that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Zain posted it out, the inner elements visibility trumps the outer elements visibility, meaning that you can not hide whole blocks of dom elements with an outer `visibility: hidden`. If anything inside the block has a `visibility: visible` explicitly set, it will show.

See also: https://jakearchibald.com/2014/visible-undoes-hidden/

Answer (score -1):

You are putting visibility to hidden then again in visible. If it has similar selectors then css gets last one. Check your classes

```css
.screens > .screen {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.screen.pt-page-current {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="screens">
  <div class="info-screen screen screen-viewer">
    <div class="screens">
      <div class="loading-screen screen">
        The page is currently loading.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-screen screen screen-viewer">
    <div class="screens">
      <div class="menu-screen screen">
        You accessed the menu.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the two outer `.screen` classess should still be invisible

Comment: @AdamBaranyai Now you can just add them class by js

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted? He is right. Try to swap places between the two styles like that:
`.screen.pt-page-current {
  visibility: visible;
}
.screens > .screen {
  visibility: hidden;
}`
Now the elements are invisible.

Comment: @IvanBeliakov by swapping the two css rules, the elements will ALWAYS be invisible, even if the `.pt-page-current` class is added to them, as the second rule will always overwrite the first.